# Why did Voldemort take Nagini with him to the battle at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Voldemort feared death more than anything. In that case, why would he take Nagini with him to the battle of Hogwarts where she could be killed, in turn destroying a piece of Voldemort's soul?

Why would he let a poorly protected piece of his soul strut about on the battlegrounds? A simple Avada Kedavra (a legal curse during the war) by one of the Order's stronger magicians would have killed it.

Comment: *"Why would he let a poorly protected piece of his soul **strut** about on the battlegrounds?"* Never saw a snake strut. Slither? Yes, but not strut.

Comment: This leads to broader question - why make a horcrux out of a _living_ object to begin with? It is easier to kill something which is alive than it is to destroy something which is not. A rational Evil Lord would make horcruxes out of titanium balls buried deep underground in random locations. Voldemort is a wacko.

Comment: @void_ptr - That's addressed [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/why-didnt-voldemort-hide-his-horcruxes-in-impossible-to-reach-places). Voldemort styles himself as the supreme master of evil. Making a horcrux out of something *mundane* simply wouldn't occur to him.

Comment: Nagini couldn't be killed with Avada Kedavra...

Comment: @Ferdaem - Voldemort has a massive inferiority complex to go along with his megalomania. Note that he refuses to admit to his parentage, styles himself as the "heir to Slytherin" (and a Lord to boot), deadnames his original name, etc etc.

Answer (score 10):

This is addressed in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows.

- **Voldemort is convinced that the safest place the snake can possibly be is *with him***

> *He would visit the Gaunt shack first, then, and **take Nagini with him:
>   he would not be parted from the snake any more** … And he strode from
>   the room, through the hall and out into the dark garden where the
>   fountain played; he called the snake in Parseltongue and it slithered
>   out to join him like a long shadow …*

- **Voldemort seems to be casting some sort of high-level *continuous protective spell* to keep Nagini from harm**. Presumably when he takes her to Hogwarts he's also periodically casting charms to keep her safe.

> *‘It is the only way, Nagini,’ he whispered, and he looked round, and there was the great, thick snake, now suspended in mid-air, twisting gracefully within the enchanted, protected space he had made for her, a starry, transparent sphere somewhere between glittering cage and tank.
>
>   With a gasp, Harry pulled back and opened his eyes; at the same moment his ears were assaulted with the screeches and cries, the smashes and bangs of battle.
>   ‘He’s in the Shrieking Shack. **The snake’s with him, it’s got some sort of magical protection around it.** He’s just sent Lucius Malfoy to find Snape.’*